# Batch, read filename backwards

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm working on a little script that moves files to a different map sorted by the last 2 characters, now my problem is, files always look like this:

```
1238184AD
1237135881AD
123477TG
```

And my problem here is, I can move files to the correct map if they have a fixed length, but they are not fixed. Sow now my question is, can I count the filename backwards so that the script will make a directory of the last 2 characters.

This is how my current script looks like:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set index=~8,2
set moveFrom=C:\Users\**\Desktop\Map\
set moveTo=C:\Users\**\Desktop\Map2\

for /R "%moveFrom%" %%f in (*.txt) do (
    echo %%f
    set "fileName=%%~nf"
    cd %moveTo%
    IF EXIST "!fileName:%index%!" (
        move /-y "%%f" "%moveTo%"!fileName:%index%!"\"
        echo "%%f" moved
    ) ELSE (
        mkdir "!fileName:%index%!"
        move /-y "%%f" "%moveTo%"!fileName:%index%!"\"
        echo "%%f" moved
    )
)

pause
```

Comment: Start counting from the other side: `set "index=~-2"` will retrieve the two last characters in the variable

Comment: Thanks, that was the soloution